# How to customize plotCounts (DESeq2) output with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I ran the plotCounts function (from the DESeq2 package). The output data is:

```
    count   Genotype    Treatment
S1  34.088493   GT1 Control
S2  34.499427   GT1 Control
S3  32.906924   GT1 Control
S4  26.794946   GT1 Control
S5  23.437114   GT2 Control
S6  39.239457   GT2 Control
S7  19.386930   GT2 Control
S8  31.955688   GT2 Control
S9  25.617728   GT1 Treated
S10 30.770155   GT1 Treated
S11 25.153999   GT1 Treated
S12 34.717601   GT1 Treated
S13 10.568029   GT2 Treated
S14 5.918380    GT2 Treated
S15 11.468775   GT2 Treated
S16 9.812912    GT2 Treated
```

The plotCounts graph looks like this:

[image: this]

I would like to get the same 4-columns looking graph via the ggplot customization. So I tried a ggplot customization with this script :

```
data <- plotCounts(dds, 
                   gene = "mygenenID", 
                   intgroup = c("Genotype","Treatment"), 
                   returnData = TRUE)

ggplot(data, aes(x="Genotype", y=count, color=Genotype, shape=Treatment)) + 
  geom_point(size=3) + 
  scale_y_log10()
```

But the result is very different than the plotCounts output :

[image: Link to the ggplot result]

I tried various writtings but none worked.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try replacing `x="Genotype"` with `x=interaction(Genotype, Treatment)` in the line `ggplot(data, aes(x = ...))`?

Comment: In addition to @Z.Lin's comment, it also looks like you should use `geom_jitter` instead of `geom_point`

Comment: Many thanks to both of you. :-) I spent many time to find a solution (in vain). Can I ask where "interaction" is documented ? I did not find it in the various vignettes I red.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to "Z.Lin" (in comment above), the solution is to replace

```
x="Genotype"
```

by

```
x=interaction(Genotype, Treatment)
```

And thanks to "bouncyball" (also in comment above): we can replace

```
geom_point
```

by

```
geom_jitter
```

in order to also make the data points not to overlap.

Finally, here is an example of the full solution :

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=interaction(Genotype, Treatment), y=count, color=Genotype, shape=Treatment)) + 
  geom_jitter(size=3) + 
  scale_y_log10()
```

And below is what it looks like in graph.

[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96NU1.jpg)

Thanks :-)